# dplyr: User defined Function in summarise() involving two input vectors

Tags: r, dplyr, weighted-average

I have a data frame of say 20 columns. Column 1 is group, column 2 is weights (not normalized to 1 or 100) and columns 3 to 20 contain data to be aggregated. There are some 250 rows but just 15 groups. So on an average for each group there are around 16-17 rows for each group.

For each of columns 3 to 20, I need to get group-wise weighted mean, weights being column 2.

As such this is easy by multiplying all columns by column 2 and then running

```
group_by(df, column1)%>%

  summarise_all(sum_na)
```

Here `sum_na` is the usual function `sum` with `na.rm=T`

And then dividing column 3 to 20 by column 2.

The problem is that there are NAs scattered in the data frame. Say for example, 150th row (belonging to group 5, say) in column 12 has NA. While calculating weighted mean for Group 5 and column 12, the denominator should exclude the weight in row 150 of column 2.

How to do this? Sorry for the long post. Unable to provide sample data as unfortunately stack overflow is inaccessible in office (posting from mobile).

Comment: Please share a reproducible example along with expected output

Answer (score 1):

Would something like this work ?

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  summarise_at(vars(col1:col18), ~weighted.mean(., wt, na.rm = TRUE))
```

You can select range of columns in `vars`. This removes `NA` values from the columns `col1` to `col18` with weight column as `wt`.

---

Tried this on this example :

```
df <- data.frame(group = rep(1:3, each  = 3), wt = 1:9, 
                 col1 = c(2:5, NA, 6:9), col2  = c(NA, 3:6, NA, 2:4))

df %>%
 group_by(group) %>%
 summarise_at(vars(col1:col2), ~weighted.mean(., wt, na.rm = TRUE))

#  group  col1  col2
#  <int> <dbl> <dbl>
#1     1  3.33  3.6 
#2     2  5.6   5.56
#3     3  8.08  3.08
```

Comment: Just to confirm before trying to run this. Say row 23 has NA in just one column. Would this row be deleted for all columns even if they have values?

Comment: @Dayne No. Only the `NA` values is ignored for calculation from that column.

Comment: So it's not working. It's showing the same error that length of x and w in weighted.mean is not equal.

Comment: Do you `NA` in weights column too ? In that case, you need to do something like `df %>%
  filter(!is.na(wt)) %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  summarise_at(vars(col1:col2), ~weighted.mean(., wt, na.rm = TRUE))
`

Comment: No didn't have NA in weights. But I guess it didn't work because the length (number of rows) of all groups are different, even with NAs included. In any case I found a way around by using `melt` from reshape2 package. Basically converted column 1 to column 18 to two columns with values in one and name in another. Then used name column in `group_by`.

Comment: @Dayne `reshape2` is [retired](https://github.com/cran/reshape2) . You might want to use `tidyr` instead. I guess something like this should work `df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = col1:col18, values_drop_na = TRUE) %>%
  group_by(group, name) %>%
  summarise(ans = weighted.mean(value, wt))
`

Answer (score 0):

We can use `data.table` methods

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, lapply(.SD, function(x) weighted.mean(x, wt, na.rm = TRUE)), 
       by = group, .SDcols = col1:col18]
```